# React - Have state changes from one package update components in another

Tags: reactjs, redux

The React code base I'm maintaining has multiple packages in it, each with their own components and reducers.  There are some points in the code where one package needs functions from another, so each package also exports a lot of its re-usable code to be used by the other packages.

Recently, I've run into a situation where I need to access Redux state in Package A and - get a load of this - update a component in Package B based on that state.  My first instinct was to just export the state object from A and then import it into B, and then bring in the props as needed in the component's mapStateToProps.

There are no errors when I do this, but the component never re-renders when the state changes.  Am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Comment: I don't know if you could make a cross-package state with redux. Have you tried with localStorage?

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick!  Edit - Would you mind making this an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you could make a cross-package state with redux.

I suggest you to use `localStorage`.